# access remote hbase in java,masterNotRunning

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Recently, need to use HBase as a database, so want to research hbase. But recently encountered a problem, many days did not find the answer.
First describe my machine. A common PC, system win7, in the win7 installed a virtual machine, virtual machines running ubuntu10, with Hadoop and HBase, they all run successfully. HBase shell and JAVA API in the virtual machine operate HBase successfully.

But the problem is that I want to access hbase use the PC machine in the JAVA API (win7) , then failed.
Hbase-site.xml is as follows

```
<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
   <value>/opt/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>hdfs://192.168.235.134:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>192.168.235.134</value>
</property>
```

/etc/hosts is as follows

```
192.168.235.134 localhost ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

PC (win7) JAVA API hbase-site.xml as follows

```
<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>hdfs://192.168.235.134:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>192.168.235.134</value>
</property>
```

PC JAVA code is as follows.

```
HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable (HBaseConfiguration.create ());
```

The following error:

```
Org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

In fact, I had look the source code, found in the zookeeper to obtain master address always returns localhost, the issue should be in this.
The source code as follows.
HConnectionManager.java

```
private Object makeStubNoRetries() throws IOException, KeeperException, ServiceException {
        ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection zkw;
        try {
          zkw = getKeepAliveZooKeeperWatcher();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          ExceptionUtil.rethrowIfInterrupt(e);
          throw new ZooKeeperConnectionException("Can't connect to ZooKeeper", e);
        }
        try {
          checkIfBaseNodeAvailable(zkw);

          !----here always return localhost-----------------------!
          ServerName sn = MasterAddressTracker.getMasterAddress(zkw);

          if (sn == null) {
            String msg = "ZooKeeper available but no active master location found";
            LOG.info(msg);
            throw new MasterNotRunningException(msg);
          }
          if (isDeadServer(sn)) {
            throw new MasterNotRunningException(sn + " is dead.");
          }
          // Use the security info interface name as our stub key
          String key = getStubKey(getServiceName(), sn.getHostAndPort());
          connectionLock.putIfAbsent(key, key);
          Object stub = null;
          synchronized (connectionLock.get(key)) {
            stub = stubs.get(key);
            if (stub == null) {
              BlockingRpcChannel channel = rpcClient.createBlockingRpcChannel(sn,
                user, rpcTimeout);
              stub = makeStub(channel);
              isMasterRunning();
              stubs.put(key, stub);
            }
          }
          return stub;
        } finally {
          zkw.close();
        }
      }
```

I'm Chinese, English is not good, please forgive me.

Comment: Can u also add your client java code which you run in client.

Comment: Did You find any solution for this problem.I am also struggling with the same issue. Please let me know your resolution.

Answer (score 0):

First add ip 192.168.235.134 into hosts file of win7 and
Check whether port 2181 is open at 192.168.235.134 or not if not open then open it.

To open a port in ubuntu please look into 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/293356/how-to-open-a-particular-port-in-ubuntu